# RegEx expression for Multiple Words

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a regular expression for finding the multiple words as described in below **example:**
Annual Program Code (APC)
The regular expression should be able to find the above if the following is searched

1. Annual
2. Program Code
3. Code
4. APC

Comment: You didn't make any research, did you ?

Comment: I did. I was not successful in obtaining the final result.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
let regex=/(Annual|Program Code|Code|APC)/g
```